# Design Issue: Background for Insert Hyperlink missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

The background for inserting a hyperlink appears to be missing.

I tried doing a full page refresh to bring down any updated CSS.

Does the `wmd-prompt-dialog` cssClass need a background defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix will go live after our next production build.